# is it good approach to parse urls yourself rather than by urlpattern match groups?

Tags: django, django-urls

Let's assume I am building a blogging app and create the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<category>.+?)/(?P<date>.+)$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
```

Then I create multiple templates adding this everywhere:

```
{% url 'myapp:post_list' category date %}
```

But then I think hmm... I don't want date there, let it be `<category> and <slug>` instead.

Then I have to change corresponding {% url tags everywhere in my templates!

Wouldn't it be better to rewrite url regex like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<url>.+?/.+)$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
```

and define some `url_split()` function somewhere, which would parse it in the views, add `url()` method or property to corresponding model and be able to use the following url tags:

```
{% url 'myapp:post_list' obj.url %}
```

and therefore never touch them in case I want to change something in my url regex/parameters etc?
Is it good design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But then I think hmm... I don't want date there, let it be 
>   and  instead.
>
> Then I have to change corresponding {% url tags everywhere in my
>   templates!

Why is this a problem?

> Is it good design

No it is not:

1. The function becomes ambiguous. It is doing too many things at once.
2. You are replicating functionality already available in the framework.
3. You have now effectively creating a choke point by creating a "blanket" catch-all request method. In this method there will be a bunch of decision tree if/else clauses and such branching is prime spot for bugs.
4. The entire purpose of doing this is for some imagined use case that may or may not happen.

From [xkcd # 974](http://xkcd.com/974/):

[image]

Comment: why haven't I thought about 3. before? that is so true, P.S.: thnx for the funny comics